# Opening last edited file from a directory

Tags: perl

I'm trying to run a perl script that opens the last edited file in a directory.
I know how to open a single file, like in the sample below, but not the last edited on `/home/test/`

```
open(CONFIG_FILE,"/home/test/test.txt");
while (<CONFIG_FILE>){
}
close(CONFIG_FILE);
```

How can I do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try doing this :

```
chomp(my $file = qx(cd /home/test && ls -1t | sed q));
```

this solution work by evaluating a shell command. `sed q` is a trick to display only the first line
`qx()` execute the shell command and get the output, see [perldoc qx](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/qx.html)

Or with pure-perl :

```
use File::DirList;
my $files = File::DirList::list('/home/test', 'M');
my $file = $files->[0]->[13];
```

The method `File::DirList::list('/home/test', 'M');` return an array sorted by modification date, whe just pick up the first one. 13 is the key for the filename.

See [perldoc File::DirList](http://search.cpan.org/~tpaba/File-DirList-0.04/lib/File/DirList.pm)

Comment: I will try this out. Could you please explain those to me, friend?

Comment: I wonder why this solution was voted down. Thanks to explain.

Comment: Sorry, friend! I thought I had accepted it. I'm sorry :/

Answer (score 4):

It read all files from `/home/test/` and takes newest one,

```
my ($last_modified) = sort { -M $a <=> -M $b } grep -f, </home/test/*>;
```

Check `perldoc -f -X`

Answer (score 0):

There's an example of how to read the files in a directory [in the documentation for the readdir function](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/readdir.html).

Once you get that going, you'll want to use [the stat function](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/stat.html) to check the mtime of each file as you look at it in the readdir.

All the rest is just programming ;-)

Alternately, you could take the last item from `ls` sorted by date: `ls -tr | tail -1`.